# Why session object is changed(JSP,servlet)?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, jakarta-ee

I set a attribute in JSP session:

```
session.setAttribute("test","123");
```

and I print **session Id** and **session HashCode** every minute:

```
out.println("sessionID:"+session.getId()+" sessionHashCode:"+session.hashCode());
```

I get the below result:

```
time:00:05
sessionID:awZ5kgzGNZf4 sessionHashCode:4861179

time:00:06
sessionID:awZ5kgzGNZf4 sessionHashCode:4861179

..

time:03:41
sessionID:awZ5kgzGNZf4 sessionHashCode:708977

..

time:03:46
sessionID:awZ5kgzGNZf4 sessionHashCode:5376793
```

in time `03:41` and `03:46`, the session object changed,

when I using:

```
session.getAttribute("test");
```

return `null`

Why is there this problem? how to fit it?

thank for help :)

(I using resin_2.1.4 web server)

---

thanks for ***Jigar Joshi - org.life.java*** help,

I try to print session properties :

```
time: 2011-03-11/04:21
sessionID:aJ5KCTx6gi-6 sessionHashCode:31002685
[session]creationTime:2011-03-11/03:32 lastAccessedTime:2011-03-11/04:21 maxInactiveInterval:1800

time: 2011-03-11/04:22
sessionID:aJ5KCTx6gi-6 sessionHashCode:5278202
[session]creationTime:2011-03-11/04:22 lastAccessedTime:2011-03-11/04:22 maxInactiveInterval:1800
```

I don't think because my resin session conf.

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you're using an almost 10 year old version of Resin? Are you certain that you're reading the right and up to date tutorials/books?

Comment: I tried resin3.1.11, But still have the same problem,the problem is to replace the server when the virtual hosts, and I wonder if the memory is the reason the virtual host?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems the case of session timeout.

Check your `web.xml`

```
<session-config>
  <session-timeout>30</session-timeout> 
</session-config>
```

After timeout idel session gets destroyed.

Comment: thanks,but session object change time is random (I already checked my resin conf file, I set `<session-max>40960</session-max><session-timeout>30</session-timeout>`)

Comment: By default most of the container sets it to 30 min, also you can set it explicitly in `web.xml`  + you can specify programatically per session using [`setMatInAvtiveInterval()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html#setMaxInactiveInterval(int)) , check for these.

Comment: I add the log in my post.please see it :)

Comment: weird!, I hope you[unknowingly] aren't programatically setting it to `null`

Comment: no.. it's a new session,and new session id same with old,but it's not has any attributes.

Comment: **For general information :** Here issue was with resin's implementation.

Answer (score 1):

How do you retrieve the session object to print its properties every minute?

> I print session Id and session HashCode every minute

Comment: using javascript setInterval() , every minute to get `session.jsp`,this jsp file will print session properties

Comment: :) it is getting interesting. The sessionId is not changed, and you call the jsp page - so i think it is not a problem with the session lifecyle. (just to be sure, you can install a session listener and monitor the lificycle events). It looks to me like a problem with the server itself - i'm not sure how resin serializes its sessions - it is possible that it tryes to save it for some reason, but fails when restoring it, or the GC collects the session object...

Comment: thanks,it's very weird,now,I try to upgrade my resin 2.1.4 to 4.0.15

Comment: BTW - are you using GAE? If so - try setting '<sessions-enabled>true</sessions-enabled>' in 'appengine-web.xml'